# Authlogic and HTTP digest auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, digest-authentication

I'm trying to find a solution to add HTTP digest auth to a site that uses Authlogic.

Authlogic itself only supports HTTP *simple* auth.

I'm googling and googling and can't find any ready solution or even an outline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Authlogic session model is called `UserSession`, you can always log a user in by creating a session manually, like this:

```
UserSession.create(user)
```

So, what you could do is use Rails' built in support for HTTP Digest authentication to authenticate the user, then if they are successfully authenticated, add the `UserSession.create(user)` call to log them in with Authlogic.

This is how I handle logging users in from, say, Twitter.